# Deserialized xml gives a null XElement

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

It seems like posting (HTTP POST) a JSON with a property that contains a xml fragment will not serialize properly if that property is an XElement in my class. Here is an example:

```
public class MYController : ApiController
    {
        public MyClass Post(MyClass postedObject)
        {
            return postedObject;
        }
    }

public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    public XElement MyXml{ get; set; }
}
```

The sent javascript object is:

```
{
  "MyDate" : "2012-12-01T12:00:00", 
  "MyXml" : "<node ln=\"node\" nm=\"1\" /><node ln=\"node\" nm=\"2\" />" 
}
```

For a reason, the XElement is always null, but DateTime is alright.

Comment: MyXml contains attributes not elements.  The tag name is"node" so the class object should be called "node" or add : [XmlElement("node")]

Comment: What JSON serializer are you using? I'd doubt it natively supports serializing to/from `XElement`.  If you're using JSON.NET, you could try implementing a [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).  Alternatively, change the property to `string` and parse it after deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Api might use JSON.NET serializer to parse the posted JSON data into .NET Class Objects; JSON serializer can only map the JSON DataTypes to C# DataTypes which means, the XML string in json data is going to mapped with C# string data type.

Ref: [DataType mappings between .NET and JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm)

Hence, you can not convert the XML string value into XElement during HTTP post request.

But, you can achieve this by adding some logic inside your Model Class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }

    public string MyXml
    {
        set
        {
            //XML element should contain only one root element
            //<MyXml> element act as root element
            string myXml = "<myXml>"+ value +"</myXml>";
            RootXml = XElement.Parse(myXml);
        }
    }

    public XElement RootXml;

}
```

--SJ

Comment: This worked. It wouldn't at first, it still assigned null. After some debugging, my xml value was incorrect, and the XElement.Parse would crash, but for some sort of reason, web api would swallow the exception.

Comment: @guiomie, if you are using third party web api, please try to get the web api documentation from their end to understand its behavior; based on the doc., try to modify the XML parsing logic as per your need. If you don't find the documentation, try to list down all the possibilities of getting wrong XML string, then try to include the logic to handle those wrong XML string value before you send it to XElement.Parse() method